# Error in integrate cypress with browserstack in browserstack dashboard

Tags: cypress, browserstack

I tried it but I got an error  in browserstack  dashboard
`
Your configFile is invalid: .\cypress.config.js

But it threw an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'cypress'
Require stack:


- .\cypress.config.js
- \cypress_package\12.9.0\win32\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@packages\server\lib\plugins\child\run_require_async_child.js
- \cypress_package\12.9.0\win32\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@packages\server\lib\plugins\child\require_async_child.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (.\cypress.config.js:1:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
    at loadFile (\cypress_package\12.9.0\win32\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@packages\server\lib\plugins\child\run_require_async_child.js:89:14)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (\cypress_package\12.9.0\win32\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@packages\server\lib\plugins\child\run_require_async_child.js:116:38)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at process.<anonymous> (\cypress_package\12.9.0\win32\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@packages\server\lib\plugins\util.js:33:22)
    at process.emit (events.js:400:28)

cypress run process exited with code 1
cypress run failed, exiting with code: 1
```

browserstack.json:

```
{
    "auth": {
        "username": "ra!!!!s_u48vKc",
        "access_key": "SAkGQf!!!!!yeh2g"
    },
    "browsers": [
        {
            "browser": "chrome",
            "os": "Windows 10",
            "versions": [
                "latest",
                "latest-1"
            ]
        },
        {
            "browser": "firefox",
            "os": "Windows 10",
            "versions": [
                "latest",
                "latest-1"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "run_settings": {
        "cypress_config_file": "./cypress.config.js",
        "project_name": "Project1",
        "build_name": "RadwaBuild1",
        "parallels": "2",
        "spec_timeout": 10

    },
    "npm_dependencies": {
        "npm-package-you-need-to-run-tests-1": "^1.2.1",
        "npm-package-you-need-to-run-tests-2": "^7.1.6-beta.13"
      }
    }
```

running command:

```
browserstack-cypress run --sync --cypress-config-file C:\Users\ZZ00VO865\Desktop\CypressFrameworks\Project1\cypress.config.js
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check if your folder structure matches the folder structure given on the BrowserStack's sample documentation for Integrating your tests with Cypress.

Post that, please replace the npm_dependencies in the browserstack.json file, the ones that you have added are just a sample dependencies given in the sample code, you will have to replace those with the dependencies that are actually required for your cypress tests.

Please add the below line of code to your browserstack.json file under npm_dependencies, you can change the cypress version as per your requirement -

```
"npm_dependencies": {            

         "cypress": "12.9.0"
}
```

Post that, please try running your tests on BrowserStack.

If you are still facing the issues, please reach out to BrowserStack Support directly through the Contact Us page mentioned on the BrowserStack website.